# Type casting in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

> [String Literals](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#string-literals) As with integer literals, their type can vary,
>   but they are implicitly convertible to bytes if they fit, to bytes and
>   to string.

How? How can I convert uint to bytes?

also is there any way to cast address-typed variable to bytes32?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions [instead of combining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) your questions into one. [That way](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

for conversion the simple `bytes32("string");` would work!

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 1):

The type conversions are mainly constrained by the internal representations. Fixed types convert to other fixed types and dynamic types (bytes, string) seem to convert. Internally, the dynamic types have a representation of length so conversion implies reorganization that we don't get by simple casting.

Fiddling:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25; 

contract Cast {

    uint n;
    string s;
    address a;

    function convert() public view {
        bytes32 b1 = bytes32(n);
        bytes32 b2 = bytes32(a);
        bytes32 b4 = bytes32("string");
        bytes memory b5 = bytes(s);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: any idea how to do this in solc 0.5.x?